# Clustering tables (with similar schema) together

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, clustering

I have been working on a problem but unable to make substantial progress so wanting some insights/advice.

I have a large set of tables (CSV files) having only column names. (Column values are not present.)

For example:

```
Users.csv --> ID, FirstName, LastName, City, Address, CardID
Usr.csv --> Residential, Name, State, UserID
```

I want to cluster files (tables) which represent similar entities. In the example above, both represent a person entity and hence should be clustered together.

Current Approaches:
I tried coming up with a similarity score b/w two tables which is based on the overlapping columns b/w the two tables and similarity b/w their table names

```
sim_score = alpha * (column similarity) + beta * (table name similarity)
where 
column similarity is a fraction of possible columns matching to a minimum 
number of columns from both table.
possible columns match is computed by generating features of each column like jaccard_3gram, 
tf-idf score etc. and thresholding the similarity to arrive at similarity score.

table name similarity is computed by computing the dice coeff. of the two tables names
```

Once sim_score is computed for all table pairs, then creating a weighted undirected graph and running a clustering algorithm (tried Markov, Girvan) to get the required clusters.

This approach is not working well when there are semantically related column names b/w two tables. I have been trying approaches around this thought process.

Is there an alternative to how this problem can be looked at? Any standard approaches in ML/NLP to tackle this. Any leads are helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Schema's are ideas with variable descriptions. One schema can relate three-entities and another, related schema could involve the same entitities and an additional entity.
Your clustering method should accommodate data with such a characteristic. Representing your schema's as graphs is one way to achieve this. Each schema node is defined by a set of attributes. The relationship between a pair of schemas is determined by a similarity metric such as the Jaccard similarity metric. You could then use a graph clustering algorithm to cluster the graphs.

Another way to think of this is to represent the schema as a document with the union of the terms in the schema being the vocabulary and then use document-clustering or topic analysis to find related schema's.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).